# printing results of base64_decode gives unexpected output

Tags: java, hash, decoding

For a class, I was given a file of base64 encoded salted sha-256 hashed passwords.

the file is in the form:

username:base64 encoded sha256 password:salt

My original thought was to base64 decode the hash so I would be left with:

username:salted hashed password:salt

then run it through JTR or hashcat to crack the passwords.

My problem is in the base64 decoding process.

my code looks like:

```
public static byte[] decode(String string) {
    try {
        return new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(string);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public static void splitLine(String strLine) 
throws Exception {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(strLine, ":");
    if (st.hasMoreTokens())
        userName = st.nextToken();
    if (st.hasMoreTokens())
        password = st.nextToken();
    if (st.hasMoreTokens())
        salt = st.nextToken();
}


public static void main(String[] argv) {
    String line = null;
    String pwdFile = null;
    int count = 0;
    try { 
         pwdFile = argv[0]; 
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pwdFile));

        line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            splitLine(line);
```

/* alternative #1: generates a lot of non-printable characters for the hash */
                System.out.println(userName+":"+new String(decode(password))+":"+salt);

/* alternative #2: gives a list of the decimal values for each byte of the hash */
                System.out.println(userName+":"+Arrays.toString(decode(password))+":"+salt);

```
            count++;
            line = br.readLine();
         }
        br.close();
        System.err.println("total lines read: " + count);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

With alternative #1, I end up with 50,000 more lines in my output file than were in the input file, so i assume some of the decoded strings contain newline characters which I need to fix as well.

How do I get back to and print the original hash value for the password in a format that either hashcat or JTR will recognize as salted sha256?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** You are trying to to work with Base64 encoded password hashes and when they are decoded, there are unprintable characters

**Background:** When a value is hashed, the bytes are all changed according to a hashing algorithm and the resulting bytes are often beyond the range of printable characters.  Base64 encoding is simply an alphabet that maps ALL bytes into printable characters.

**Solution:**  work with the bytes that Base64 decode returns instead of trying to make them into a String.  Convert those raw bytes to Hex representations (Base16) before you print them or give them to Hashcat or JTR.  In short, you need to do something like the following (it happens to use Guava library):

```
String hex = BaseEncoding.base16().encode(bytesFromEncodedString);
```

This is condensed from [a longer answer I posted](http://www.phpsolvent.com/wordpress/?p=3548)